# Documentum DQL Getting list subfolders from a few folders

Tags: documentum, emc, documentum-dql

everyone!
I am starting with Documentum this month and here is my problem.
There is multi-select drop-down list with cabinets. I have to choose some of them to get list of inner folders in my result list below.
This query:

```
select * from dm_folder where folder(id($param$))
```

or

```
select * from dm_folder where folder($param$)
```

where param is object_name

works with single drop-down select. 
I've tried to insert "in"

```
select * from dm_folder where folder in($param$)
```

results with

```
[DM_QUERY_E_SYNTAX]error:  "A Parser Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of:  select * from dm_folder where folder in"
```

or

```
select * from dm_folder where folder(id in($param$))
```

results with

```
select * from dm_folder where folder(id in ('0c0511d48000105',' 0c0511d48000106'))

[DM_QUERY_E_SYNTAX]error:  "A Parser Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of:  select * from dm_folder where folder(id in"
```

and return multivalue flag in queries above but it doesn't work.
Can someone help, please? Thank you!

Comment: can you add more details on how you tried to insert IN, and how does it not work? It's not clear what is the problem you are dealing with

Comment: thanks for your comment i've edited post and added more information

Comment: you are writing a query the wrong way, I'll write in an answer the correct format

Comment: You mean dql selectors with CAPSLOCK?

Comment: upper or lower case on keyword letters in query doesn't matter

Comment: I've edited your question since you are a new user. Please validate that I didn't changed something with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
SELECT * FROM dm_folder WHERE r_object_id IN ('0c0511d48000105',' 0c0511d48000106')
```

I think it's clear where you made an error. Keyword FOLDER you used is function that accepts single value as parameter.

From DQL guide:

```
The FOLDER predicate
The FOLDER predicate identifies what folders to search. The syntax is:
[NOT] FOLDER(folder_expression {,folder_expression} [,DESCEND])
The folder_expression argument identifies a folder in the current repository. You cannot search a
remote folder (a folder that does not reside in the current repository). Valid values are:
• An ID function
• The ID function (described in The ID function, page 29) identifies a particular folder.
• A folder path
A folder path has the format:
/cabinet_name{/folder_name}
Enclose the path in single quotes. Because cabinets are a subtype of folder, you can specify a
cabinet as the folder.
• The keyword DEFAULT
The keyword DEFAULT directs the server to search the user’s default folder. Note that a user’s
default folder is the same as the user’s default cabinet (because cabinets are a subtype of folders).
```

**Edit 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM dm_folder WHERE ANY i_folder_id IN ('0c0511d48000105',' 0c0511d48000106')
```

With this query you are looking for folder type objects whose parent is any of the folders specified as the parameter.

**Edit 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM dm_folder WHERE i_cabinet_id IN (<list of ids>)
```

This will return you all folder objects under cabinet

Comment: Yes, I've also tried it before I found an example with FOLDER () selector... but it shows nothing. Although query executes successfully it says...

Comment: Well, syntax is OK now, but you need to work on semantics - what do you want to found out with this query?

Comment: Ok. So it seems that I can't use FOLDER, but what should I use?
As you can see in my question post I use $param$ inputs that come from multi-select drop-down list. In single-select FOLDER works perfectly. But what should I use instead in this situation?

Comment: OK, I probably understand what are you trying to achieve. You are searching for folders under one or more specified folder. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you!

Comment: I think this is what are you looking for. i_folder_id is a mutlivalue field storing id's of the parent folder of the object. object can be linked to multiple folders - there for this is a mutivalue field. That's why we need to use keyword ANY in where clause

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't show anything, although query executes successfully.

Comment: Sure I'll accept!)
Does it matter that in drop-down multi-select appears list of cabinets? And I need folder inside them?

Comment: Express yourself in the context of the query you specified. The list of cabinets you are talking about are the id's in the WHERE clause?

Comment: You mean the source of the list? It is (SELECT * FROM dm_cabinet) in list show object_name and as value comes out either r_object_id for example.

Comment: Then all should be fine, you are missing something here. It's up to you to find the problem. Maybe there are no any folder under those Cabinets?

Comment: Hmm, but this query ```select * from dm_folder
where folder( id('0c0511d480000106'))``` shows me list of folders.

Comment: Hm, I don't have time right now to go in the details, will do it later. Try with one more thing for now: SELECT * FROM dm_folder WHERE i_cabinet_id IN (<list of ids>) This will return you all folder under cabinet, but through whole folder structure, this can be problem for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time it seems to be work! I'd check it browser and feed back.

Comment: When you will have time please update your answer, i'll accept it